# SQL statement - one result to be divided with another

Tags: sql

I'm very new to this SQL world so it might be a dumb question.

I have this table "page_load" with, amongst others, the columns "page_title","user_id" and "utm_source". I can view the total of distinct "user_id" with filter on "page_title" with this simple code:

```
SELECT count(distinct "page_load"."user_id")
FROM "page_load"
WHERE "page_title" = 'Discover'
```

And I can view another filter with this one:

```
SELECT count(distinct "page_load"."user_id")
FROM "page_load"
WHERE "utm_source" = 'recommend"
```

Well, can I get the second result to be divided by the first?

This way I can get the percentage of the second based on the first on a SQL question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ratio with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN utm_source = 'recommend' THEN user_id END) /
               COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN page_title = 'Discover' THEN user_id END)
FROM page_load
WHERE utm_source = 'recommend' OR page_title = 'Discover';
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but would adding `WHERE page_title = 'Discover' OR utm_source = 'recommend'` to this have the potential to make it run faster?

Comment: You can't do that because the OP wants to take a ratio.

Comment: How would this modify the output? Does it not just limit the number of returned rows so that the `CASE` has less rows to look through, without losing any of the necessary rows for the calculation?

Comment: You're correct, I thought you were suggesting somehow using a single `CASE` expression.